# How to Ensure a Unique Email, userName will Enter into MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
db.UserSchema = new db.Schema({   
    userName: {type:String,
        unique:true,
        required:true,index:true},
    emailId: {type:String,
        unique:true,
        required:true,index:true},
    password: {type:String,
        required:true},
    contactNumber: String,
    region: String,
    isActive:Boolean,
    lastLoginDateTime:Date
});
```

Above is the schema I would like to put into MongoDB, but email and userName should be unique and I am unable to do that.

Comment: try username:{type:String, required:true, unique:true} and do the same for email

Comment: The above question needs a bit of tender love and care to meet SO standards with respect to formatting (a very little bit of which I have done - if it's accepted) and making the question more readily apparent to those looking to be helpful Expand you question a little bit, make it clearer, and - if you are able - provide some attempts at a solution or some links to documentation that you are reading. Here's the link on questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @joao its not working that way ,i have tried.

Comment: Did you remove the index:true part? Specifying unique:true already creates the index.

Comment: @joao yes dear i have removed that also,still not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this way and it worked

`db.UserSchema = new db.Schema({ 
    userName: {type: String, index: {unique: true, dropDups: true}},
    emailId: {type: String, index: {unique: true, dropDups: true}},
    password: {type:String,
        required:true},
    contactNumber: String,
    region: String,
    isActive:Boolean,
    lastLoginDateTime:Date
});`