# Custom Validator to check if the Username is Unique

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, validation, asynchronous

I am using *express-validator* to validate my forms.
I am able to validate everything except for checking if the username is unique.

Since I am using *Mongoose* for *MongoDB*, searching the database is asynchronous.

- *How do I create a custom validator to check if the username is unique?*

This is how I search the database:

```
// Call the model function to find a user by their username
User.getUserByUsername(username, function(error, user) {
    if ( error ) throw error; // If there is an error throw it
});
```

This is the *getUserByUsername* function:

```
module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback) { // Find a user by their username
    var query = {username: username}; // Set the query to search for matching usernames
    User.findOne(query, callback); // Find one object with the given query and call the callback function
}
```

*I am not sure how to incorporate this into a Custom Express Validator. I tried doing something like this:*

```
app.use(validator( { // Use Express Validator
      customValidators: { // Create custom validators
        usernameExists: function( username ) { // Create a validator with the name of 'usernameExists' and make it a function
          User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user) { // Call the model function to find a user by their username
            if ( err ) throw err; // If there is an error throw it
            if(!user) { // If the user doesn't exist
                // Return false
            }
            // Otherwise Return true
          });
        }
      }
} ));
```

The problem here being that *getUserByUsername* is asynchronous, meaning I can **NOT** use **return** from inside that function.

Later on, I would use the custom validator like this:

```
req.checkBody('username', 'Username is already registered.').usernameExists( req.body.username ); // If the username already exists
```

- *How do I return the custom validator properly? I tried using **Promise**, but unsuccessfully.*

Comment: You also need to consider the possibility that two requests for the same username might happen at roughly the same time. Because the call is async if the second call happens after the first but before the first processes the results, both will see the username as unique and you will end up with a duplicate user. If you were using Java you might use synchronization but since you are using Node you have fewer options.

Comment: I suspect you will have to enforce username uniqueness at the database schema level.

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28649593/how-to-ensure-a-unique-email-username-will-enter-into-mongodb-using-mongoose

Comment: Good thinking. I will definitely look into this matter. I thought of doing something like that, however I need to be able to use the custom validator. Is there a way of doing it with the Express Validator?

Comment: I don't think so. Because fo the concurrency issue you will probably just have to attempt to create the user and respond with an error message if the db rejects the request.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same thing, but thought that maybe I overlooked something. I will try doing it this way. I will leave the thread here, to see if some one comes up with a better solution. Thanks!